# Authentication for GET Request in Android HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: android, apache, heroku, https, http-headers

I tried but there seems to be a problem in making a GET Request to a heroku URL example  "https://xxxx-xxxxx.herokuapp.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx"

I know the general method is

`HttpClient client = factory.getHttpClient(); //or any method to get a client instance
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);`

And I know that getState() is not available for 3.x version.

I don't know how the Chrome's "Advance REST Client" has handled it, it gave me the pop up and asked for the username and password and I entered Credentials and it worked and since then its working fine. I thought It might have stored the credential locally but, its not the case. I checked all the cookies and cache. I deleted the extension and cleared data and its still working.

Then I tried to use another REST Client by WizTools (for Mac). In the Authorization section there are 3 options. 1.) Basic, 2.) Digest and 3.)Preemptive, I did some permutation and combination with it using the given Credentials but all the time it gave the same response i.e.

"HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable"

I don't understand what's the issues is?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

I don't know, if why is it not working, but I used [URLConnecton](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) used the authentication mentioned and it worked. I got the response. And yeah BTW I had to assign the "Accept" type a s "Application/Json"

Comment: this worked for me.  added: request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");